# Set VirtualHost for Tomcat 8 webservice on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, virtualhost, httpd

In addition to the default Apache on AWS EC2 Linux I have installed Tomcat 8 and deployed a webservice on it.

The current URL (which works) is http://example.com:8080/MyService/api/generatePath

I want to make this shorter with a subdomain api.mydomain.com, so that I can use this URL: http://api.example.com/generatePath.

This is what I have done on the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, but it doesn't work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.example.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/MyService/api
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/MyService/api
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First have you enabled mod proxy on apache? Secondly try remove    `ProxyPreserveHost On`

In addition make sure the port is opening; easiest way to check is go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ (Enter website address and port 80)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

(1) To remove the `/MyService/` part of your url, rename your `MyService.war` file to `ROOT.war` and copy it to your webapps folder using `sudo cp`. Normally, your tomcat installation is expected to automatically generate a ROOT directory in the same folder.

(2) To remove the :8080, access the site via :80 instead which is not listed on the URL bar, using the installed `httpd.conf` you stated. Edit the following two things to look like this.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.example.com

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    <Location "/">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```